# Show last update date

Tags: sql

I am new in this forum and also new in SQL my question is

I have an Excel sheet link to database with "From Microsoft query" I have 3 tables link together pd_ln,pdcflbrt,pdlbr

By using the following query I am getting this data

```
SELECT pdcflbrt.lbrcod, pdcflbrt.lbrrat, pd_ln.prdnum, pdcflbrt.begeffdat
    FROM velocity.dbo.pd_ln pd_ln, velocity.dbo.pdcflbrt pdcflbrt, velocity.dbo.pdlbr pdlbr
    WHERE pdlbr.lbrrattky = pdcflbrt.lbrrattky AND pd_ln.pd_ln_tky = pdlbr.pd_ln_tky 

+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------------+
|    lbrcod    |       lbrrat |  prdnum   |    begeffdat     |
+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------------+
| FC Braselton | 0.11         |     00236 | 7/15/2012 0:00   |
| FC Braselton | 0.11         |     00236 | 7/15/2012 0:00   |
| FC Braselton | 0.1          |     00236 | 12/10/2012 0:00  |
| Sizing       | 0.21         |     03103 | 8/28/2015 0:00   |
| Sizing       |         0.2  |     03103 | 10/13/2011 0:00  |
+--------------+--------------+-----------+------------------+
```

How do I query to get the last begeffdat of each prdnum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magood's answer may work in this situation. However, if there was a unique identifier for each edit that you were selecting, it wouldn't work. As far as I know, you would have to get involved with `row_number()` like so:

```
SELECT s2.lbrcod, s2.lbrrat, s2.prdnum, s2.begeffdat from 
    (SELECT pdcflbrt.lbrcod
    , pdcflbrt.lbrrat
    , pd_ln.prdnum
    , pdcflbrt.begeffdat
    , row_number() over (partition by pd_ln.prdnum order by pdcflbrt.begeffdat desc) as RN
    FROM velocity.dbo.pd_ln pd_ln, velocity.dbo.pdcflbrt pdcflbrt, velocity.dbo.pdlbr pdlbr
    WHERE pdlbr.lbrrattky = pdcflbrt.lbrrattky AND pd_ln.pd_ln_tky = pdlbr.pd_ln_tky) s2
where s2.rn = 1
```

This will return only the top date (it is the same query on the inner portion, but with the `row_number()` function added, with each different `prdnum` starting the numbers over, and ordering the rows by date, with the newest date first. The outer portion selects only row 1 (that's the last `where`) which is the newest date.

EDIT: Alternatively, if you only want the OLDEST update, you could change the `desc` in the main query's `select` statement to say `asc`.

Comment: getting error "Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Oops. Forgot a `from`. Try it now.

Comment: Thanks a lot phroureo

Answer (score 0):

-- Only for name and latest date

```
select lbrcod, max(begeffdate) begeffdat from @table
group by lbrcod
```

-- For all columns

```
select * from (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by prdnum order by begeffdate desc) rowNum from @table
) data
where rowNum = 1
```

Comment: will you explain little more how do I add this code with my query?

Comment: The query above will get you only the name and the latest date.
If you want all the columns, use the new query I added.